# Possible ways to connect Access application to SQL server in different server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

let's say there are a couple of tables in SQL Server. My client is using Access 2003 database at their own server. SQL Server 2008 R2 is at diff server. Their Access front end is written in VBA. I know I could let them connect to my SQL server using ADO and OLEDB provider. For this they would have to add a reference from

```
Tools-->References--> MS ActiveX objects 6.0 Library
```

And with the provided connection string:

```
Provider= SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial catalog=DatabaseName; Data source =ServerNamethathostsSQLSeerver
```

Are there any other ways to let them connect to the SQL Server? 
What are some better ways to do so in terms of performance?

Please share your opinions. Thanks.

Comment: You could use ODBC too but OLEDB is a better solution.

Comment: @simon OleDB is on the way out [Microsoft SQL Server, codename "Denali", will be the last release to support OLE DB, ODBC is the new new thing](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/microsoft-sql-server-codename-denali)

Comment: As suggested here – Open Database connectivity is the preferred choice. So, no, oleDB is not a better solution or even a better choice (such a suggestion is one of those myths born by those in this industry that are out of the loop so to speak). In fact, we cannot use oleDB for SQL Azure, but the recommended Open Database Connectivity choice works just fine.

Comment: Point taken but the OP is using 2008r2 and that and OLEDB are going to be around for a long while yet. The MS move to ODBC is driven by Azure and their strategy of moving away from proprietary technologies. This doesn't necessarily make OLEDB a bad choice today.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your inputs. I m trying to understand, learn and test some possible scenarios for the case I presented in my post. OLEDB, ODBC are fine. Is there a way to create a web service in C# and then let Access VBA front end talk to web service to get access to SQL server and do READ/select * operation? Is that a possibility? Please let me know what are the some pros and cons with this method. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Access 2007 and on, the recommended way is linked tables, no references are required, it can be done through code or from the menu. Microsoft Access 2003 also supports linked tables.

More info: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-access-to-sql-server-data-HA010341762.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your input Remou. But the client doesn't want linked tables way. Our team will only host their backend tables. They will need some mechainism to connect let their front end VBA application to talk to our SQL server db that resides in diff server than their Access db. Any thoughts, suggestions, articles etc will be helpful. TIA.